# Possible for client to edit geoJSON on server?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geojson

I am a webmapping newbie so pardon any misnomers I am probably making.

I have a geoJSON file that represents garbage cans as lines running along a street (i.e. the line is an aggregated representation of all the cans on that street, so if 1 can is 20 lbs and there are 3 cans on the street, the line feature on that street will have a weight attribute of 60 lbs).

These lines have four attributes: weight, time (seconds per picking up all cans on that street), number of cans on the street, and the route number that services them. These attributes appear in a div at the bottom of the screen when you click/select a given line:
[image]

Is it possible to allow the user/client to change the route attribute value in a manner that it changes the original geoJSON and then refresh the web page to see the new changes (lines are symbolized by route number)?

Comment: The answer to your "Is it possible to...?" question is: [Yes](http://www.strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html). It'll be useful to know what you've tried already, and whether the geojson is a static file in a webserver or if there is a GIS backend generating it. It's possible, but the solutions will depend on the current architecture of your system.

Comment: As you've tagged GeoServer as the server software, the standard way of doing this would be to configure a transactional WFS service.